# run the selenium as django command

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-rc

I have the problem with downloading file from website using selenium in Django 1.3.(Python 2.7+).

I have done the django management command to download the file in **selenium firefox webdriver**

Actually,the downloading box is in modal dialog,For solving this modal dialog problem I referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)

Everything was fine in python console when testing the Django management command.since, command name is "download_keyword"

```
 >>>python manage.py download_keyword
 >>>
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",os.getcwd())
```

The firefox downloaded file is not stored in this location.But it is downloading also No exception occurs.

This is my firefox profile preferences:

```
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
    print "DIR is..",DIR
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",os.getcwd())
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/csv")
    fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time",600)
    fp.set_preference("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time",600)
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Even I have given the various location to store the downloading file from selenium firefox driver.Eventhough it is not stored in the given location.

What i would supposed to do? suggest me for this error