# How to handle Save As dialogue box of firefox in Selenium usng C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am looking to download a file/report from a website to my local folder. I am using Selenium with C#. Until now I was able to click the download button, dialogue box open for Save as or open option. Can any one help me in Saving file to folder in MyDocuments via Firefox dialogue box?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Seems the same as this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox

Comment: "Until now" - why, what's changed? The latest Firefox version? There's [this old FAQ](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-HowdoIdownloadafile%3F) too.

Comment: Thanks for refrence. but this not work for me

Answer (score 1):

This is still an open enhancement request, so it shouldn't have ever worked for you unless you had something else handling the browser modal dialog.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=95

Ken