# selenium firefox download

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am using python selenium and would like to download a pdf file, however it opens in my browser? How can I download it from my browser? Any way to click the following image, 
[image]

Before, all i had to do was disable the firefox download box dialog, but now I am not able to request the download. Any ideas?
What should i do to request the download? I am also not able to find the file on the server.

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/vnd.csv")
```

Comment: are you using selenium RC or Webdriver ?

Comment: I am using selenium webdriver

Comment: seems is very similar with that issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759256/selenium-firefox-profile-for-saving-a-file/12772521#12772521

Answer (score 0):

There is no way do do it with selenium in a way you described. However you can tweak your browser, so it doesn't open pdf's but downloads them - and that can be done with selenium.
[Here's](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=profile) (How to auto save files using custom Firefox profile )a good example how to do it.

Comment: I have already tried that. It doesnt download just opens it in a pdf viewer in the browser.

Comment: as we can't see the webpage nor your code, it is hard to say why doesn't it work for you...if nothing else, use requests.

Comment: What about a context click, because it downloads if you do context click> save link as..., i can make a context click but do not know how to select the `save link as` option,code:                                                        `download_element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(download)
        ActionChains(driver).context_click(download_element).perform()
        ActionChains.click('link=Save Link As...')`

Answer (score 0):

With [AppLoader](http://nrgglobal.com/apploader) you can click on any button, icon, or shortcut, just like a real user.

Answer (score 0):

Add

profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled",True)

That will disable the default pdf viewer in firefox.

Also your save-to-disk preference seems incorrect. It should be 
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf")

The last thing to keep in mind is that if you have multiple file types to download, you need to put them all under the same set_preference saveToDisk statement, comma separated, otherwise the later statement will overwrite the earlier settings.