# Unable to suppress a firefox pop-up for a file download

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium3

[image]Firefox - 51.0.1
Selenium - 3.0.5
Ubuntu - 16.04 (64bit)

Here is what my code looks like:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.dir'] = "/tmp/webdriver-downloads"
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf"
profile['pdfjs.disabled'] = true

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
driver.get "https://s3.amazonaws.com/shopsocially-misc/vfs/vfs_test_sample.csv"
```

Please run the above code and than you see the popup.

This is the error I get:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Failed to decode response from marionette
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:85:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:85:in `create_response'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:63:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:615:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:126:in `get'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in `to'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:132:in `get'
    from (irb):70
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

As far I tried, it seems an issue with the new versions I am using. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: it's not a popup, it's a download confirmation, and you want to set it so, that it never asks if to save or not. Look at answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759256/selenium-firefox-profile-for-saving-a-file (i.e. `firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");`)

Comment: Did not work. I added the dialog box I get when I hit the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MIME type is tripping you up. In your example you have it set to 'application/pdf'. I have downloaded the file with wget to determine the mime type.

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/shopsocially-misc/vfs/vfs_test_sample.csv
  ...
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Length: 200 [application/octet-stream]
...
```

The content type of **application/octet-stream** means that the server itself [doesn't know what kind of file this could be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061617/2730283). Since Selenium is explicitly defining what MIME types it will accept in `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`, this is causing your failure.

This profile will help to automate downloading different types of files, including **application/octet-stream**.

```ruby
# Create a firefox driver that can be passed to HeadlessBrowser.new
def start_driver
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile["browser.download.folderList"] = 2 # This allows downloads to be sent to a custom location
  profile["browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting"] = false
  profile["browser.download.dir"] = `/home/stefan/Downloads` # download to this custom path

   # FILES WILL NOT DOWNLOAD UNLESS THEIR MIME TYPE IS INCLUDED IN THIS LIST!
  profile["browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"] = accepted_mime_types_for_download

  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
  return driver
end

def accepted_mime_types_for_download
  [ 
    "application/vnd.ms-exceltext/csv",
    "application/csv",
    "application/zip",
    "text/csv",
    "application/x-msexcel",
    "application/excel",
    "application/x-excel",
    "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "image/png",
    "image/jpeg",
    "text/html",
    "text/plain",
    "application/msword",
    "application/xml",
    "application/octet-stream"
  ].join(",")
end
```

Comment: @TheRookie you could consider awarding the bounty by clicking the little `+50` button next to the answer.