# Unable to pen MS Word Document from Firefox browser

Tags: selenium

In Selenium, When I try to open MS Word Document from Firefox browser, dialog box pop-ups which I am unable to identify through Selenium. Can any one please help me in identifying the dialog box (How to capture ID or window ID) through selenium?

Comment: Refer to the solutions here: Access file download dialog in Firefox.

Cheers!

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can use **autoit**.Just Download the autoit software from given link and install it.

[AutoIt Site](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

Write a few lines script in autoit according to your need and call the compiled exe before the line which causes that window to appear.

The **Autoit WIndow Info Tool** will help you in identifying the ID and class for the desired controls.