# How to extract data from a visual popup on Chrome web scraper plugin?

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, selectors-api

i'm trying to extract data (logo image, name, location, etc) from this website : https://websummit.com/startups/featured-startups?q=eyJwYWdlIjoxLCJjb25maWd1cmUiOnsiaGl0c1BlclBhZ2UiOjQ4LCJ0YWdGaWx0ZXJzIjpbIndzMjEiXX19

The problem is that when clicking on an image, a visual popup appears (the url doesn't change) so i tried various selectors (site map example i used : home >> popup selector (with the Multiple option) >> text selectors for name, location etc) but none of them works (i could see the data but after scraping no data is available)

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the site map or what selectors to use to access the data in the visual popups ?

Comment: This thread might be helpful for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789023/interacting-with-pop-up-boxes-using-selenium-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the selector button, I used the popup link selector with CSS I extracted from the page, then selected multiple checkboxes

```
ID  Selector    type    Multiple    Parent selectors    Actions
startup-logo    .MuiPaper-root.MuiCard-root.jss51.MuiPaper-elevation1.MuiPaper-rounded  SelectorPopupLink   yes _root
```

[image]

I've also created the following child selector

```
ID  Selector    type    Multiple    Parent selectors    Actions
startup-name    span.jss53  SelectorText    no  startup-logo
```

[image]

[image]

This approach works for me for all other selectors, but it does not work for PopupLink,
which leads me to believe the popup link selector is broken.

This is corroborated by multiple pages saying the plugin [returns no data](https://forum.webscraper.io/t/no-data-scraped-yet/1578/9).

So essentially, stop using this plugin and instead use other alternatives.
Here's a few that I know of:

- [DataScraper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-scraper-easy-web-scr/nndknepjnldbdbepjfgmncbggmopgden)
- [Octoparse](https://www.octoparse.com/) - has a free trial option
- [Parsehub](https://www.parsehub.com/) - has a free trial

Alternatively, if you are willing a bit of programming, take a look at [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) as it is the ultimate tool for gathering data.