# How to handle Excel download popup using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

- How to handle Excel download popup using Selenium WebDriver

[image: Excel download popup]

Answer (score 1):

You must create/modify the browser profile to auto download/save the excel file which happens on pop up (or) can use Robot class to handle window pop ups.

Refer [How to download any file and save it to the desired location using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746707/how-to-download-any-file-and-save-it-to-the-desired-location-using-selenium-webd?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
//common to all the cases
FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();

//Case:1 - Use this case to set download this code to your browser's default location
//prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");
//prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");

//Case:2 - Download file to Desktop
//prof.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 0);
//prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");
//prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");


//Case:3 - Download to custom folder path. Replace d:\\selenium with your Download Location 
prof.setPreference("browser.download.dir","D:\\selenium\\");
prof.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");


//Set Preference to not show file download confirmation dialogue using MIME types Of different file extension types.

prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"//MIME types Of MS Excel File.
    + "application/pdf;" //MIME types Of PDF File.
    + "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;" //MIME types Of MS doc File.
    + "text/plain;" //MIME types Of text File.
    + "text/csv"); //MIME types Of CSV File.

//This will work for all cases mentioned above
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
driver.get("http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[1]/td[4]/a[text()='Download']")).click();
```