# How to handle file download in Internet Explorer 11 using Ruby-Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, browser-automation, webautomation

I'm new to **Ruby-Watir** automation. I want to save a file, after clicking on "Download Report" link available on the web page(Opened in IE-11). It's giving me  a pop-up to save the file at bottom of the browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWzQW.png)

Can anyone please help me with Ruby-Watir code to handle such popup in Internet Explorer 11? Kindly let me know if any other details required.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that it isn't possible with Selenium and Internet Explorer, without [mucking with the registry or using AutoIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792415/how-to-download-a-file-from-ie-browser-using-webdriver-selenium). Downloading with IE requires interaction with the operating system, which is beyond Selenium's capabilities.

Also, here's an article about why you probably actually [don't need to test downloads](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/), regardless.

Comment: No way to disable this pop up? This wouldn't happen in Chrome.

Comment: IE is definitely not Chrome. :)

Comment: Yes, I am asking you whether is there anyway can we disable this pop up by changing any of the internet explorer setting? Possible?

Comment: I think my answer above sufficiently addresses your question

Comment: I think you don't understand what I am asking.

Comment: You are "... asking [me] whether is there anyway can we disable this pop up" to which I've already said: "The simple answer is that it isn't possible with Selenium and Internet Explorer, without mucking with the registry or using AutoIT". There's a link in the answer if you want to explore the options discussed there.

Comment: Yes, I have also found later that it can't be handle using selenium/watir alone. AutoIT  and RAutomation are possible solutions to handle this, but I did't get any compact solution using either of this. titusfortner the link you have given isn't opening, not sure whether the link is broken or due to access restriction I'm not able to open the link. Can you please post here AutoIT code to handle above mentioned notification bar coming in IE-11 so that I can call/incorporate that code in my ruby-watir script. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @titusfortner That's what I said you did not understand what I have been asking. I did not ask whether we can handle that pop up. I asked you whether any internet option to disable that pop up!