# How can I download a file on a click event using selenium, using 'webdriver.Ie()' only?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver

I am constrained to use `webdriver.Ie()` only, for the `.aspx` page I am required to download the file from, opens only in Internet Explorer.

Can somebody show how to accept the 'save file' dialogue upon clicking download button?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are getting this kind of Save popup while clicking on the download button?

[image]

If yes then Selenium web driver does not provide any way to click the Save button on that popup.

You need to use any third-party library to click on the Save button on that popup.

To get more information, I suggest you refer to the links below.

1. [How to handle download file on IE 11](https://longvuinautomationworld.wordpress.com/2017/06/01/how-to-handle-download-file-on-ie-11/)
2. [Downloading a file in Internet Explorer through Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/downloading-a-file-in-internet-explorer-through-selenium)
3. [Download a file in IE using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695031/download-a-file-in-ie-using-selenium)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I will check the links you've shared. However, I was wondering if it were possible, to silence the pop-up window, just as one could, using webdriver.FirefoxProfile().set_preference('<argument in javascript>') method for firefox browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, since in IE 8, there is no option to disable download dialog. For this reason and the fact that IE web driver doesn’t support manipulation browser preferences, there is no simple way to manage downloading files in Selenium. Ref: https://blog.j-labs.pl/2017/02/Selenium-Webdriver-browser-preferences-for-downloading-files