# Handling OS Popups using Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, popupwindow

A reporting application has an `Export to Excel` link which upon clicking opens a OS popup similar to the one shown below.

**Internet Explorer**

[image: Export OS Popup]

**Firefox**

[image]

I need to click on the `Save As`(IE) or `Save File`(FF) button and provide the path I need in the 'Save As' popup window and save the file. I'm aware of the `driver.getWindowHandle()` functionality but I'm not able to handle OS popups using this method.

Please let me know if there is anyway in Selenium or in Java to handle OS popups in any browser like the above ones.

**EDIT**: I believe answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox) is restricted to Firefox. What I am looking for is a solution for handling this kind of native OS popups that works across all browsers (at least in IE, Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download any file and save it to the desired location using Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746707/how-to-download-any-file-and-save-it-to-the-desired-location-using-selenium-webd)

Comment: You will have to handle this for each browser dependent on the browser because Selenium doesn't handle anything outside of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You need use Firefox profiling to overcome from this issue:-

```
        FirefoxProfile pro=new FirefoxProfile();

        pro.setPreference("browser.downLoad.folderList", 0);

        pro.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "Applications/zip");

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(pro);
```

- browser.download.folderList controls the default folder to download a
  file to. 0 indicates the Desktop; 1 indicates the systems default
  downloads location; 2 indicates a custom folder.
- browser.download.dir holds the custom destination folder for
  downloading. It is activated if browser.download.folderList has been 
  set to 2.
- browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk stores a comma-separated list 
  of MIME types to save to disk without asking what to use to open the 
  file.

Below code for chrome multiple download option:-

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", getClass().getResource("/data/input").toString().replace("%20", " ").replace("file:","").replaceFirst("/", ""));
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

For IE Refer :-

```
http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/
```

You can also use Robot class of java but it can lock your screen for  while

You need to use ROBOT class for firing an ENTER Action event. In java if you want to fire any event you have to use Robot class for typing using programatically or firing events like ENTER and ESCAPE.

```
// Create object of Robot class
Robot object=new Robot();

// Press Enter
object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

// Release Enter
object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Please get back to me if still facing issue :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not able to try your answer since I'm having an issue with my FF browser. Once it is fixed, I will let you know whether it works. Meanwhile It will be helpful if you know any methods or APIs that will help me handle these popups across all browsers

Comment: once you initialize firefox with the above profile it will be set for throughout the session, so you don't need to worry at each download action :)

Comment: That's fine. By 'across browsers' I meant, a solution that works in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Chrome browser will be a better approach since the Chrome will not open the file download pop-up.But multiple download option should be enabled if you need multiple downloads.

Comment: I'm not really worried about multiple downloads. I will just put it straight to you - Are there any methods to handle these kind of native OS popups, independent of the type of browser used?

Comment: I have updated my code. Did you downvote me? I need to delete this answer if yes

Comment: Absolutely not. Why would I down vote you? At least you cared to provide a valid solution to my question rather than **trying** to find duplicates or finding faults like some ppl here ;)

Comment: +1 for the edited solution. Will try out your suggestions and accept your answer if it works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think above answer is useful only when we have to Save the file / download the file on local machine. Operating system's native dialogs such as Save As, Open are not controllable by selenium web driver. 
I use **AutoIT** (only for Windows OS)to handle windows specific pop-ups.
You may refer [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for initial understanding.
So here, invoke autoIT script when you click on any Web Element that will handle further OS specific operations such as Saving file, browsing file to upload etc.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on using AutoIT (probably with an example) for handling these popups?

Comment: Assuming you have gone through above link to understand what AutoIT is. Consider here [Example of Selenium+AutoIT](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/upload-a-file-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoit)

Comment: Sorry to redirect you on other websites. I would have given my code but I am not good at editing that in comments ;). Plus that link will provide better understanding :) Also, that is just an example. You will find several blogposts providing code samples for using  AutoIT.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code. It worked for me :

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                "application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\SampleExcel");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Enjoy :)