# How to auto-download through Firefox browser using FirefoxProfile?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

I'm working with selenium java where I need to download pdf files, I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746707/how-to-download-any-file-and-save-it-to-the-desired-location-using-selenium-webd) and also [this](http://yizeng.me/2014/05/23/download-pdf-files-automatically-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver/) answers here, but seems like nothing is working in my situation. 
Is it due to setting a new firefox driver instance i.e.`System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "D:\\FFF\\firefox.exe");` ? I'm stuck here.However when I manually click on save file on the MIME dialog it saves correctly to my custom location, also my download link code resides in another java class and below code in another class , but  I use the same driver as declared in this class,
below is my code,

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
//Set Location to store files after downloading.
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\WebDriverDownloads");
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf"); 
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "D:\\FFF\\firefox.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: why `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` option is commented, what type of file you are downloading. if you are unsure check in network tab in chrome while downloading the file

Comment: sorry, my bad, its pdf file only, edited question

Comment: what happens when you click on the link that is suppose to download the file, does it opens in another tab

Comment: Yeah..it opens a blank tab for a millisecond and then opens up a MIME dialog where  it ask for either 'open with' or 'save file'.

Comment: could you try `application/x-pdf` also try manually after setting this properties in `about:config`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code block configures a `Firefox Profile` to `Download` and `Save` PDF files using `Selenium` through `Java` bindings:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Utility\\Downloads");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/vnd.pdf");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/vnd.pdf");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "D:\\FFF\\firefox.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: It is not working , also I'm not sure why it pops out a new  blank browser tab for a millisecond and closes immediately before showing a dialog, is it causing any  issue ?

Comment: Nopes, can you please get a snapshot of both `new blank browser tab` and `showing a dialog`? Which type of files are you trying to download exactly?

Comment: okay ..I cant get the screenshot of blank tab as it open for fraction of second before opening. here is a screenshot of MIME dialog 
http://imgur.com/a/iiVhh

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know if that works else consider sharing the url.

Comment: Initially I didn't cover the edge cases which was a bug in my code. Now covered the edge cases as well :) Thanks

Comment: The first "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile" setting seems unnecessary.