# How to automate downloading "txt.htm.xls" file format using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have an application where user click on icon and a file get downloaded. The extension of the file is:

> txt.htm.xls

I have set the preference:

```
             profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");
```

but this is not working as it seems to be incorrect [MIME](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/) type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-download in firefox browser with java-selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589571/auto-download-in-firefox-browser-with-java-selenium-not-working)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am able to download pdf correctly but this is an issue with format "txt.htm.xls"

Answer (score 0):

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
        "text/plain,text/html, application/xml");
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: No. I am not able to solve the problem using above code.