# Automatically download files using selenium Chromedriver 3.11.0 on a Mac

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, mutablecapabilities

I've read through a bunch of selenium topics on here and I've been going in circles on how the permissions / options should be set for the chromedriver. I've made the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/username/chromedriver");
String downloadFilepath = "//User//username//automation-testing//";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

The call to the download page is made using a simple

```
driver.get(url);
```

which redirects to a csv file.

I keep getting a popup prompt asking me if downloading files is okay.  It's worth mentioning that the new ChromeDriver(cap) line is deprecated, but I can't seem to find documentation on how to use the method that replaced it that covers this use case.

Comment: simply `new ChromeDriver(options);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that I used was pretty intense full source below to log into jira via google below, then download a filter view to csv (current selection) below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Scrape {
    public static void doScrape(String[] urls) {
        try{
            for(String url : urls) {
                //Create new Chromedriver, set file download path, allow the download popup to be automatically accepted,and merge the properties into chromedriver
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/damienbell/chromedriver");
                String downloadFilepath = "/Users/damienbell/automation-testing";

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--test-type");
                //options.addArguments("--headless");
                options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

                //Instantiate above options in driverService
                ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
                ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);


                Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
                commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");

                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("behavior", "allow");
                params.put("downloadPath", downloadFilepath);
                params.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");


                commandParams.put("params", params);
                ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
                CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
                String command = null;
                try{
                    command = om.writeValueAsString(commandParams);
                }catch(JsonProcessingException jpe){ jpe.printStackTrace(); }
                String postURL = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + driver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
                HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(postURL);
                postRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                postRequest.addHeader("accept", "*.*");
                try{
                    postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
                    httpClient.execute(postRequest);
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { uee.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }


                driver.get("https://x.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=11502");
                Thread.sleep(3000);  // Let the user actually see something!
                ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById("menu-sign-in").click();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById("google-signin-button").click();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById("identifierId").sendKeys("email@email.com");
                Thread.sleep(700);
                ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById("identifierNext").click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=password]")).sendKeys(Secret.getPassword());
                Thread.sleep(600);
                ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById("passwordNext").click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                driver.get(url);
                Thread.sleep(56000);
                File[] files = new File("/Users/user/automation-testing").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File path) {
                        if (path.isFile()) {
                            ParseCSV.doParse(path);
                            path.delete();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Failure");
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                driver.quit();
            }
        }catch( java.lang.InterruptedException inter ){ System.err.println("Thread.sleep broke something, wtf"); inter.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you were almost there. You need to use the method [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *ChromeOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *ChromeOptions* object as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/username/chromedriver");
String downloadFilepath = "//User//username//automation-testing//";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.merge(cap);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

PS : As a reference you can have a look at the discussions in [**`mutablecapabilities`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutablecapabilities) tag

---

### Update

As per your comment update as you are stuck with the *download confirmation window* you can look at the discussion [**Auto-download in firefox browser with java-selenium not working**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589571/auto-download-in-firefox-browser-with-java-selenium-not-working/45590783#45590783) to solve your issue.

Comment: Oddly enough, even after these changes I'm still getting a confirmation window when I run this -- do you have any insight as to why?

Comment: @A_Elric My answer was constructed as per your baseline question `It's worth mentioning that the new ChromeDriver(cap) line is deprecated, but I can't seem to find documentation on how to use the method that replaced it that covers this use case.`. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new ticket. Satckoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: the question is about the download not happening due to a popup window- though mentioning that this may be partly because I was not using mutable capabilities tag -- after changing the tags over, I remain blocked on the larger issue.  I'm happy to upvote you for your efforts though.

Comment: @A_Elric Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: I am uncertain that solution will work with chrome, as the arguments are likely different...

Answer (score 1):

On python's selenium library I've added to the webdriver.ChromeOptions() object the "headless" argument so it won't show the chrome window - Means no download prompt.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
```