# Firefox headless crashing on headless redhat linux machine

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, headless

I'm trying to run selenium tests on a headless redhat linux build machine using firefox headless. My method to create the driver looks as so:

```
private static WebDriver createFireFoxDriver() {
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver()
            .setup();

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setHeadless(true);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FOLDER);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/json");

    return new FirefoxDriver(options);
}
```

The error I'm seeing in the log files looks like:

```
[Parent 65433, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (82): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
[Parent 65433, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 727

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x1E0074,name=PBrowser::Msg_StopIMEStateManagement) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x1E008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

1579539977190   Marionette  TRACE   [11] Frame script loaded
1579539977191   Marionette  TRACE   [11] Frame script registered
A content process crashed and MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN is set, shutting down
```

I've checked that we have the correct versions of gtk, glib, pango, xorg, and libstdc++ installed on the machine as well. Has anyone run into this problem before with a headless build machine?

Firefox version: `68.4.1` | Selenium version: `3.141.59` | Geckdriver version: `0.26.0`

Digging deeper into the test that is causing the crash. Right before the crash occurs the test is clicking on SwaggerUI's API try functionality. No other action on the site causes this crash to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that works as well as the root cause.

When running firefox within a linux docker container, `/dev/shm` must have at least 2gb. My build machine configuration was not meeting this requirement. Increasing the amount of memory to a value over 2gb solved my problem immediately.

The reason for this behaviour is that Firefox uses POSIX shared memory which on Linux (according to the `shm_open(3)` man page) is based on `tmpfs` (expected to be) mounted on `/dev/shm`. Open shared memory objects/interfaces can be listed with the `ipcs` or `lsof` utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any version misatch in the binaries you are using with respect to the discussion in [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403).

The sole suspect is the [**`setHeadless()`**](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#setHeadless-boolean-) method of [FirefoxOptions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) class which as per documentation is as follows:

```
setHeadless(boolean headless)
```

So effectively, your code block will be:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setHeadless(true)
```

---

### Update

Additionally the *Keys*:

- `browser.download.folderList`
- `browser.download.dir`
- `browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting`
- `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`

needs to be configured through **`setPreference()`** method using an instance of **`FirefoxProfile()`** as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FOLDER);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/json");
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to auto-download through Firefox browser using FirefoxProfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589571/how-to-auto-download-through-firefox-browser-using-firefoxprofile/45590783#45590783)

Comment: Yes. setHeadless(Boolean) adds the "--headless" argument to the initialization of the browser

Comment: @st0ve Do you see any error once you set `options.setHeadless(true)`?

Comment: I've editted my original text. `HEADLESS` is a boolean value that is always true on the build machine. So `options.setHeadless(true) == options.setHeadless(HEADLESS)`

Comment: @st0ve Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I just tried it out. Still seeing the issue :(. I've dug deeper into the test surrounding the crash and added it to my original post