# Executable download settings for Chrome and Firefox in Selenium Webdriver 2.8.1

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, webdriver

Trying to figure out how to handle download dialog (non-javascript dialog) for an executable plugin (non-flash) in Chrome and Firefox browsers as part of a Java Selenium framework.

The dialog has two options:

1. Cancel
2. Download and install the executable plugin in browser

What are the ChromeOptions or FirefoxProfile preferences that I can use to handle this dialog?

1. Either to download by default
2. Or to handle the two buttons separately (Cancel & Download)

It's not really a question of downloading and saving the file, but actually running an executable after download.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download any file and save it to the desired location using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746707/how-to-download-any-file-and-save-it-to-the-desired-location-using-selenium-webd)

Comment: Its not really meant to download+save. The question is focusing on download+running an executable to install a plugin in the browser.