# Issues while downloading a file from a website using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I have to download 2 files from a website and rename the files based on the report type and move it to the specific folder.

[image]

I tried downloading the file using xpath but unable to do so.

```
//*@id="ctrl1805929160"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[1]

public static void execute(WebDriver wd) throws Throwable{
wd.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do");  
Thread.sleep(2000);
List<WebElement> list= wd.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),06)]/parent::tr/td[10]/a"));
int i = 0;
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\NEA558\\Desktop\\New_Folder\\Files"));
for (WebElement element:list)
{
    i++;
    element.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println((element.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),06)]/parent::tr/td[10])["+i+"]")).getText()).substring(0,3));
    String report_type = (element.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),06)]/parent::tr/td[10])["+i+"]")).getText()).substring(0,3);

} 
}
```

Table source : https://www.shipper-ml.com

[image]

[image]

I am getting below error message when I am executing the code.

```
Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(),'0123456789'),'06')]/parent::tr/td[1]/a}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:513)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:356)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
at package1.Test_new.execute(Test_new.java:80)
at package1.Test_new.main(Test_new.java:105)
```

I believe I am doing some mistake in giving the xpath. Can somebody help me with that.

Comment: Can you post your code & table source? Are you trying to click on the table row?

Comment: Hi @Sureshmani, I have updated the question with the code and also the table source. Any help from you will be highly appreciated as I need to fix this asap.

Comment: What browser are you using? Each browser will have different limitations for downloads and need to be handled differently in the code. Also, your table source links to a page behind a login wall. Use `driver.PageSource` to get the html and add it as a gist (github text file), or something else, to this question. Also, what file extension are the excel docs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download any file and save it to the desired location using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746707/how-to-download-any-file-and-save-it-to-the-desired-location-using-selenium-webd)

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? Can you please update post with html of the table? The link that you provided in OP is forcing for the login to shipper.

Comment: I need to automate the process wherein it should automatically download the required file from the website

Comment: @supputuri, I have updated the post with html of the table.

Comment: @Asyranok, file extension is .csv and I am using Chrome browser. I have attached the html part in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this thread. Are you still looking for the help on this issue?

Comment: No, I resolved it.. Thanks for the reply, but...