# How to click on hidden object using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('http://www.example.com')
username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
username.send_keys('username')
password.send_keys('password')
browser.find_element_by_id('submit').click()
```

I want to click on the download button (lower right second one).

Please help me!! The following code did not work:

```
browser.find_elements_by_id('//input[@value="EE"]').click()
```

Comment: Does `browser.find_element_by_id('originator_node').click()` work?

Comment: Also: you're calling `find_elementS` and then calling `click`. You probably don't want that.

Comment: @l19 that also does not work. actually when i click over that it should start downloading .tar.gz file

Comment: An `<input type="hidden">` is *not* a clickable.  The button you want is some other element.  It's probably inside the table somewhere.

Comment: Have you debugged this? Can you split the line into two and see what `find_elements` returns?

Comment: @Zack I can really click over the download button, but i could not make it through selenium

Comment: @l19 it gives <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003DC9FD0> using browser.find_element_by_id('originator_node')

Comment: How many elements are returned?

Comment: @l19 sorry, i could not get how many elements

Comment: I don't know how to tell you to generate the event you want, because *you have shown us the wrong part of the document*.  Messing around with a random `<input type="hidden">` that happens to be in the same form is not going to accomplish anything.

Comment: @Zack I am very sorry. You are right! I have uploaded new image, please have a look.

Comment: Your images are now completely gone :-(

Answer (score 2):

depend of how many similar links you have on that page try:

```
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(
                              'https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/download/').click()
```

for more locating options [see the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)

also, note that you'll have to add the chrome equivalent of [Access to file download dialog in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox) to avoid a download dialog

Comment: your code does not work anymore, can you provide working code? @Guy

Comment: sorry, it's hard to tell without the real html, use print statements to debug the html element you are locating, you'll have to somehow find the relevant `a` link and click on it...