# access to upload/download modal browser dialog

Tags: c#, selenium

I need access to upload/download modal browser dialog. Is this functionality supported by Selenium (I didn't found information in wiki) or maybe someone know workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

User cannot manipulate with modal windows.
If you want to upload the file, you should use additional libraries. For example, Java Robot. It's the quickest and easiest solution. You can only paste the full path to the file.

Comment: Actually, I can download data via Chrome but in IE and FF I get modal dialog (http://kb.mozillazine.org/images/FxOpening-doc.png). As you see the dialog have option "save as" and cheackbox "..apply action for all data like this". This cheackbox is disabled in my FF  and I need found some other way to work with this dialog. Also I try  enable auto download event using profile like there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox) but I get crash when I try change property via profile.SetPreference()..

Comment: Did you set the profile property before the browser instance creation?
You can try to use the SikuliWebDriver to catch dialog windows and click OK button.
https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver

Comment: Yes, I tried set property before creating browser. Thanks for Sikuli, I'll look into it but I'm not sure that I can use some extra lib in project..