# Selenium IDE Test for broken download links

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I just want to know the good approach and ways to check if the download links in a page is not broken. Is it the same as checking the broken links?

Answer (score 1):

As the [download file dialog is a browser window to which selenium has no direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox) you have two options:

1. Configure your browser to auto-download the flies to some directory, click on the link and check the file
2. Get the href value of the link and check the response code with other utilities than selenium.