# Use sikuli-script on different OS

Tags: java, webdriver, sikuli, sikuli-script

I'm writing scripts on Java with Selenium WebDriver. To navigate with Windows Windows and other programs I decide to use sikuli-script in my project.
But, I didn't think what will be if these scripts will run in other mashines on MAC OS, Linux, there will be other pictures and my script will crush.
First what I think it's take pictures on all mashines and put in different folder for different mashines. 
For example I will have 3 folder for 3 Operation System: Windows, Linux, MAC.
And if test will start on Linux it will take "navigate pictures" from Linux folder, if MAC or Windows - the same (from MAC or Windows folders).
But may be there's some better decision of it?

---

Yeah, and don't write me to use AutoIT, cus it's not working in my case, because I need control Java app on Windows, and AutoIT can't work with it.

Comment: Have you checked that screen shot taken on windows works on MAC and Linux to detect the web-element?

Comment: Not yet. but I think for example if I download smth on windows and on MAC, there are different save window, and script will be not working

Comment: Can you tell me what are the browsers you are using on different OS? I can handle the scenario with different approach.

Comment: Right now it's FireFox, but script will be implemented also on IE and Safari.
Well what I did not. I've download file, after open downloaded archive and extract it to disc C:\

Answer (score 0):

Lets Optimize the Download operation by avoiding clicking on Download file, Open Download and then saving it to Disc.
We can use Selenium itself to perform all the operations by using browser profiles with the required configurations.

All the required changes you need to do with the Firefox and on Safari Mac can  be found at [MAC](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/) and for [Firefox](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-download-files-using-selenium-webdriver/) also please refer to the Link where you can get more ideas around the scenario. [Downloading file using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox/9329022#9329022)

Comment: ok, I'll try a little bit later, cus should write framework, and after will be give u an answer