# How to set Firefox preferences when using nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\downloads");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

How can I set properties like `browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting` when using nightwatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding the only way to accomplish this is to create a profile before hand and use that profile in nightwatch configuration, similar to the insructions here: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Enable-Firebug-in-Firefox-for-Nightwatch-tests

I wish there was a way to set firefox preferences, since with the solution I'm providing your tests are dependent on running on the machine with the profile.