# Access webdriver object in Seleno

Tags: c#, selenium, seleno

I am using Seleno for UI testing. Under the hood, it uses Selenium:
https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.Seleno

I need to interact with a download pop-up for Firefox.
A previous question's answer uses Selenium's webdriver:
[Access to file download dialog in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)

How can I apply this solution in Seleno?