# Ruby interacting with Selenium to control Firefox open/save dialog

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, dialog

`Capybara.register_driver :session do |app|
        profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
        Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, :profile => profile
      end`

What do I add here to get my ruby scripts to tell Selenium (I am running on a MAC OS El Capitan) to interact with the Firefox Open/Save dialog box such that it opens a PDF or DOC file automatically instead of prompting me with the dialog box which requires manual intervention?

Comment: I don't know what do you want, any more detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to file download dialog in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)

Comment: I looked at the one link above but it is hard for me to parse through lots of answers (some of which aren't relevant).   I want to know what ruby code I need to add to the statements above such that when the dialog box comes up, I can choose whether to open the pdf in the browser with a plug-in or to save the file away.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with the Open/Save dialog box using selenium-webdriver with firefox.  However, you can set preferences in your driver to make the dialog box never appear and a default behavior to just happen.  Something like

```
Capybara.register_driver :session do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['browser.download.dir'] = "~/Downloads"
  # Adjust below to match the type of file reported
  profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf, application/octet-stream" 
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, :profile => profile
end
```

should cause it to always download the files without prompting.  You can similarly set the 'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile' profile setting to have specific types of files always be opened.

Comment: It still gives me a dialog box when trying to open a PDF file.   Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
 Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new  
    profile['browser.download.dir'] = "~/Downloads"
    profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/doc, application/pdf, application/octet-stream"
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, :profile => profile
  end

Comment: Any good reference to the man pages for the command above in your answer would be great too as well as a description of a browser profile would be appreciated.  Thank you.